# How do I activate code folding in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to know how to put these squares that can hide lines and show then again later

[image: This squares with a "minus"]

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you are attempting to do? In the example you provided the folding is visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are asking about is called [code folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding) and allows for easier navigation and editting of the file.

If the file you are editing has been given a language highlighting template from the Language menu option, the boxes will appear automatically. Using your example, it has the HTML code highlighting applied to it. This can be applied manually by clicking Language > H > HTML.

There are further options for folding under the View menu.
[image: Screenshot of the View menu in Notepad++]

If your file doesn't have a code style applied you cannot use folding.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Menu `Settings >> Preferences >> Editing`, choose `Box tree`

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that this only works if a code highlighting template is applied to the file.

Comment: @Burgi: Yes, you're right but I guess OP knows that already, may be I'm wrong.

Comment: It is a little unclear, we both could be guessing here. I've flagged it to ask for more clarity.